# Intuition difference between derivatives of $\exp (x) $ and $\log (x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

It is well known that the exponential function $\exp (x)$ has the derivative $$\frac{d}{dx} \exp (x) = \exp (x).$$ However, its inverse, the (natural) logarithm, $\log (x)$, in fact changes after derivation: $$\frac{d}{dx} \log (x) = \frac{1}{x}. $$
I understand why this is correct, but this is not intuitive to me. Why does $\exp (x) $ not change after derivation, while $\log (x) $ does and they are just mirrored at $y = x $?

**EDIT:** Thank you all for your answers, they really helped me understanding this!

Comment: Log and experience are different functions. Why would their derivatives behave the same?  Okay experience an log are inverses and inverses are reflexive over the line y=x.  So the derivative of $f(x)$ at x=k will be 1 over the derivative of f inverse at x=f(k). Let j=exp k and k =log j.  The derivative of exp(x) at x=k is exp (k). So the derivative of log at x=exp (k)=j is 1/exp(k) = 1/j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(a) = b$ and $f^{-1}(b) = a$ all continuous and differentiable, then 
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}]_{x = b} = \frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}]_{x=a}}$$

Think about that in terms of slope of the tangent. When you reflect the graph of $f(x)$ which here is $e^x$, the reflection across the $45^{\circ}$ or $y=x$ line is $f^{-1}(x)$ which here is $\ln(x)$.

The point $(a,b) = (a, e^a)$ reflects to $(b, a) = (e^a , a)$

The slope of the tangent to $f = e^x$ at $(a,b)$ is $e^a = b$

The slope of the tangent to $f^{-1}$ at $(b,a)$ is, by geometry of the reflection and definition of slope, the *reciprocal* of the above slope = $1/b = 1/e^a$

Being careful that $(x, y)$ have different meanings on the two graphs (which is why I specified a point $(a,b)$ rather than getting tangled in $x$'s and $y$'s),
the slope of the tangent to $f^{-1} = \ln(x)$ at $(b,a)$ is $1/b = 1/x$ for the "new" x on the inverse function.

You are expecting the *equations* in written form to be symmetrical, which they aren't, because of difficulties of notation and our definitions of functions. But the graphs are meaningfully symmetrical.

Answer (score 2):

Heuristically, $exp(x)$ has a derivative that is equal to the image of the function, thus it quite naturally follows that its inverse will have a derivative that is the inverse of the pre-image.

Comment: That's very nice way of putting it!

Comment: I really like your answer, simple and short!

Answer (score 2):

We can look at it geometrically.

Let $f(x)=e^x$, so $f^{-1}(x)=g(x)=\log(x)$.
Any function's inverse should look like its reflection over $y=x$. Let's consider a point $(x,f^{-1}(x))=(x,y)$ on the graph of log.

By definition, $f(y)=x$. As you know, the tangent line to $f$ has slope $e^x$, so the tangent line to $f$ has slope $s_f=e^y$. We want the slope of $g$.

Well, since the graphs are reflections over $y=x$, so too should be the tangent lines. So, its slope should be the reciprocal of the slope of the other line:
$$
s_g = \frac{1}{s_f} = \frac{1}{e^y} = e^{-g(x)} = e^{-\log(x)} = \frac{1}{e^{\log(x)}} = \frac{1}{x}
$$
Thus, based on this geometric argument, the derivative of $g$ should be $1/x$ (since that's what the slope of the tangent line should be).

See [here](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage6/Lesson/inverseDeriv.html) for some pictures.

Indeed, in general:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x) = [f'(f^{-1}(x))]^{-1}
$$

---

Also, I like to look at the Taylor (or MacLaurin) series:
$$
e^x=\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
$$
\log(1-x) = -\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_n x^n
$$
Notice that term-by-term differentiation causes $e^x$ to become "itself", and that the same action on $\log$ causes it to become the same as $(1-x)^{-1}.

Not sure if it helps with intuition though.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the chain rule, you can start from
$$
x = e^{\ln x}
$$
and take the derivative on both sides:
$$
1 = e^{\ln x}(\ln'x) = x\ln'x,
$$
such that $\ln'x = 1/x$. Alternatively,
$$
y = \ln(e^{y}),
$$
so that
$$
1 = e^{y}\ln'(e^{y}).
$$
Rename $x=e^y$, and you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If $f $ and $f^{-1}$ are reflexive over the line $y=x$.

So at the point $(k,j) $ the derivative of $f$ is $f'(k) $ and so the derivative of $f^{-1} $ at $(j,k) $ will be ${f^{-1}} '(j)=\frac 1 {f'(k)} $.

So if $f=\exp $ and $f^{-1}=\log $ we have that at the point $(k,j=\exp (k))$ we know $\exp'(k)=\exp(k)$.  Therefore at the point $(j=\exp (k),k)$, we know $\log'(j)=\frac 1 {\exp (k)}=\frac 1j $.

====

Interesting to note that by the chain rule:

$f\circ f^{-1}(x)=x $

So $(f\circ f^{-1})'(x)=f'(f^{-1}(x)){f^{-1}}'(x)=1 $

and ${f^{-1}}'(x)=\frac 1 {f'(f^{-1}(x))} $

which is interesting.

And it means $\log'(x)=\frac 1 {\exp' (\log (x))}= \frac 1 {\exp(\log (x))}= \frac 1x $

And if we want to be perverse:

$\exp'(x)=\frac 1 {\log'(\exp (x))}=\frac  1 {1/\exp (x)}=\exp (x) $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be related by

$$ y = \exp(x) \qquad \qquad x = \ln(y) $$

Then, this derivative becomes

$$ \mathrm{d}y = y \, \mathrm{d} x $$

or, if you don't like differentials,

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = y $$

Either way, it's clear this isn't anything resembling being symmetric in $x$ and $y$. There's no reason that 'mirroring' them should give a result of the same form.

Instead, we have
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{1}{y} $$

---

That said, if we invert *differentiation* rather than inverting *$\exp$*, we do get something similar; e.g.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^x \exp(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \exp(x) $$